# Regex Split Split Generically

Tags: regex

I have the following String:

```
[Tag|String|WORD0120151218]
```

With the following Regex:

```
(?<=\|)([^|]+$)(%[^"]]|)
```

This Regex currently gets everything after `[Tag|String|` so essentially it returns: `WORD0120151218]`

I've been trying for a few hours now (new to Regex) to get `WORD` (but this could be anything, it should meet the format a-zA-Z). And I've been trying to get the date from this (again this could be any date).

Any ideas?

Comment: `0120151218` is the date?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. 01 is just a random generated number, it could be any amount of digits, the date is: 20151218 - maybe it's possible to grab the last 8 digits (the date)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use capturing group.

```
.*\|([A-Za-z]+)
```

Get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uD2iX4/2)

To get also the datae.

```
.*\|([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)
```

Comment: What about the date at the end?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. 01 is just a random generated number, it could be any amount of digits, the date is: 20151218 - maybe it's possible to grab the last 8 digits (the date)?

Comment: try `.*\|([A-Za-z]+).*(\d{8})`

Comment: Perfect, you're great!

Comment: Do you know how to express these in Java? To put in a string and just replace with these two groups?

Comment: ya, `string.replaceAll(".*\\|([A-Za-z]+).*(\\d{8}).*", "$1$2")`

Comment: How can I get it so it keeps the template: [Tag|String|WORD0120151218] but just replaces the values?

Comment: `string.replaceAll("(.*\\|)([A-Za-z]+).*(\\d{8})", "$1$2$3")`

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is consistent, i.e. `[somethingHere|anotherThingHerre|wordDate(numbers)]`
You can use this regex: `\[\w+\|\w+\|([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)]` So that `$1` will give you `WORD` and `$2` will give you `0120151218`.

Comment: How can I just get the date regardless of how many characters there are in front of it, e.g. 01, or 0101 then the date?

Comment: `\[\w+\|\w+\|([a-zA-Z]+)\d+(\d{8})]`